# Is it possible to clean up this procmail filtering a little

Tags: clamav, procmail

I have this procmail filter which seems to work, but which I'm really not proud of. I'm convinced that we can do much more optimized and clean with nested sections, but I can't achieve any functional results.

```
:0
* !^X-ClamAV
VIRUS=|/usr/bin/clamdscan --no-summary --stdout -

:0fw
* !^X-ClamAV
* VIRUS ?? .*: \/.* FOUND
| formail -a "X-ClamAV: Yes, $MATCH"
:0Efw
* !^X-ClamAV
| formail -a "X-ClamAV: Virus Free"

:0
* ^X-ClamAV: Yes
$MAILDIR/.virus/
```

You may have understood, I try to tag the email headers with `X-ClamAV: Yes, $MATCH` or `X-ClamAV: Virus Free` depending on the clamdscan result and place it in $MAILDIR /.virus/ if positive.
That's all.

**EDIT:**

May be this is better:

```
:0
* !^X-Virus-Status
VIRUS=|/usr/bin/clamdscan --no-summary --stdout -

:0
* !^X-Virus-Status
* VIRUS ?? .*: \/.* FOUND
{
        :0fhw
        | formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Infected, $MATCH"
}
:0Efw
| formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Virus Free"

:0
* ^X-Virus-Status: Infected
$MAILDIR/.virus/
```

(I changed tag to be able to filter with AddHeader from clamav-filter)

**EDIT2:**

But I made the mistake of not explaining well, or not explaining at all that in fact, the email can be tagged before procmail (clamav-milter) and therefore already contain `X-Virus-Status: Infected`. In this case there is no point in repeating the scan, but you must place the email in `.virus`. This is why I need to put

```
:0
* ^X-Virus-Status: Infected
$MAILDIR/.virus/
```

out of braces

But my solution seems not good (`procmail: Skipped "--no-summary --stdout -"`):

```
:0
* !^X-Virus-Status
{
        VIRUS=|/usr/bin/clamdscan --no-summary --stdout -

        :0
        * VIRUS ?? .*: \/.* FOUND
        {
                VIRUSNAME=`echo "$MATCH" | sed 's/ FOUND$//'`
                :0fhw
                | formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Infected ($VIRUSNAME)"
        }
        :0Efw
        | formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Virus Free"
}

:0
* ^X-Virus-Status: Infected
$MAILDIR/.virus/
```

I don't want to overwrite the `X-Virus-Status`.

- If not tagged -> scan -> tag (infected or not) -> put in `.virus` if infected
- If already tagged -> put in `.virus` if infected

In other words (maybe more clear):

```
1) tagged X-Virus-Status?
    yes:    go 2)
    no: scan -> infected?
                yes: tag infected
                no: tag non infected
2) tagged X-Virus-Status: Infected?
    yes: put in .virus
    no: go 3)
3) continue procmail filters
```

**EDIT3:**

The solution I tried in EDIT2, the same as proposed by @tripleee, was good. The problem was about the filter which args were not read.

I replaced

```
VIRUS=|/usr/bin/clamdscan --no-summary --stdout -
```

by

```
VIRUS=`/usr/bin/clamdscan --no-summary --stdout -`
```

and it seems to be ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick stylistic note, the braces are unnecessary here.

```
:0fhw
* !^X-Virus-Status
* VIRUS ?? .*: \/.* FOUND
| formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Infected, $MATCH"
```

The `fhw` flags apply to the action and it's only taken if the conditions match.

On the other hand, I would probably use a set of braces around all the actions you want to take when these conditions are true.

As an alternative to fix the syntax errors, try backticks around the VIRUS assignment. It's possible to use the `=|` assignment syntax as well, but if the first doesn't work for you, try the other. It works fine for me here.

```
:0
* !^X-Virus-Status
{ VIRUS=`clamdscan --no-summary --stdout -` }

:0
* !^X-Virus-Status
* VIRUS ?? .*: \/.* FOUND
{
    :0fhw
    | formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Infected, $MATCH"

    :0
    $MAILDIR/.virus/
}
:0Efw
| formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Virus Free"
```

Perhaps it would also be useful to drop the last "FOUND" token from `MATCH` before writing it to the header.

```
:0
* !^X-Virus-Status
* VIRUS ?? .*: \/.* FOUND
{
    VIRUSNAME=`echo "$MATCH" | sed 's/ FOUND$//'`
    :0fhw
    | formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Infected, $VIRUSNAME"
```

(I was struggling to come up with a solution which wouldn't require an external process to trim the end of the string. Maybe something like that could be accomplished with clever use of scoring, but it's probably overkill for this simple recipe.)

Finally, I'm not sure whether you want to overwrite the `X-Virus-Status` even if it was already there. Your `:0E` will happen when either or both of the conditions are false. Perhaps you meant this instead;

```
:0
* !^X-Virus-Status
{
    VIRUS=`clamdscan --no-summary --stdout -`
    
    :0
    * VIRUS ?? .*: \/.* FOUND
    {
        VIRUSNAME=`echo "$MATCH" | sed 's/ FOUND$//'`
        :0fhw
        | formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Infected, $VIRUSNAME"

        :0
        $MAILDIR/.virus/
    }
    :0Efw
    | formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Virus Free"
}
```

In other words, only take these actions here if `X-Virus-Status:` was not already present in the headers; if the result from Clamscan indicates that there was no virus, add the header "Virus Free".

I took out the `/usr/bin`; probably better make sure your `PATH` is sane than hardcode all paths, but of course, up to you ultimately.

With your updated question, I guess the logic you want is

```
:0
* !^X-Virus-Status
{
    VIRUS=`clamdscan --no-summary --stdout -`
    
    :0
    * VIRUS ?? .*: \/.* FOUND
    {
        VIRUSNAME=`echo "$MATCH" | sed 's/ FOUND$//'`
        :0fhw
        | formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Infected, $VIRUSNAME"
    }
    :0Efw
    | formail -a "X-Virus-Status: Virus Free"
}

:0
* ^X-Virus-Status: Infected
$MAILDIR/.virus/
```

Comment: Very interesting thank you. I edited my question to adapt better to my wish. We are almost there

Comment: I updated with a new solution at the end. Is something missing still?

Comment: Thanks, but...The problem is that the solution you propose to me is identical to the one I gave (within the path) in EDIT2 of my question, but this causes an error message (which I indicated) and it doesn't work. The mail is tagged X-Virus-Status: Virus Free. I FOUND it; solution in my post

Comment: Oh right, I failed to update that everywhere. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Ok, but, why do I see that form (=|filter args) everywhere, and especially why does that form works perfectly in others configuration and not just when we add braces?

Comment: I don't use that syntax much myself but both should work. I was wrong about it being a standalone assignment; all I can say is your first example works fine here (replacing `clamdscan` with `nl` since I don't have ClamAV installed here).